# Conditions for the satisfiability of a matrix inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, reference-request

Let $X\geq 0$ be a positive definite matrix and $A$ a square matrix, do there exist conditions either on $A$ or $X$ (or both) such that
$$
X-AXA^\top\geq 0,\quad \quad (*)
$$ 
holds, where $\top$ denotes transposition?

My first (naive) guess was the following one: if the eigenvalues of $A$ are in modulus less than 1, then $(*)$ is met. However there are plenty of counterexamples that disprove the previous statement.

Any help/suggestion/comment is welcome!

Comment: One obvious condition is that $\kappa(X) \|A\|_2^2 \le 1$, where $\|A\|_2$ is the operator norm of $A$ and $\kappa(X)$ is the condition number of $X$ with respect to the operator norm, but I doubt this is useful.

Comment: What you are looking for is the discrete Lyapunov equation. It is a well studied equation and the condition should be related to the eigenvalues of A. You can find it in wiki and many other websites and articles.